# C++ partial initialization with curly braces

Tags: c++

Is this initialization valid by standard? Would it create empty vector so that I could push data (`vector<Pair<float, string> >`s) into it later?

```
struct A
{
    int a;
    int b;
    vector<vector<Pair<float, string> > > c;
};

A obj = {1, 2};
```

Comment: Yes. `A` is an aggregate, so `obj.a` is initialized with `1`, `obj.b` is initialized with `2`, and `obj.c` is initialized from `{}` - i.e., value-initialized.

Comment: What does it mean `A` is aggregate? `A` is a `struct`.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Comment: This has been permissible for a long time, it is not new to C++11.

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pair could be changed to `std::pair` (`#include <utility>`) in case Pair is not defined
In the corrected program (below), partial initization allowed, it prints, 1, 2, 0, as `c` gets initialized too as a no-element vector.

```
struct A
{
    int a;
    int b;
    vector<vector<std::pair<float, string> > > c;
};

A obj = {1, 2};

int main()
{
    cout << obj.a << ", " << obj.b << ", " << obj.c.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I agree. std::pair is just a suggestion, may be Pair has been defined elsewhere, if not, then std::p[air may be used

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Edited my ans, made as Could be instead of Should be :-)